# Is there anyway to get Microsoft Store account email address associated with the purchase in UWP?

Tags: email, uwp, account, windows-store

I am trying to build an app that can be downloaded on multiple devices. We want to be able to get the email address associated with the Microsoft Store account used to download and install the app.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to get Microsoft Store account email address associated with the purchase in UWP?

No, there is no such way to get the customer's email. If the customer brought your app using his Microsoft account. Then he will be able to download your app in any device that is logged with his Microsoft Account.

Comment: Problem is many customers use multiple MS accounts, unfortunately, the account associated with the local MS store on a particular device device is not always the same and they get confused.